Best Way To Authenticate Firebase JWT in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API
I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API that I want to authenticate a Firebase JWT within during the request pipeline. I have reviewed this page https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#c yet I am curious what is the best way to authorize a Firebase JWT token in .NET 6 as part of the request pipeline?
Currently I am doing this and then utilizing the [Authorize] attribute:
builder.Services
       .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddJwtBearer(options =>
           {
               options.Authority = "https://securetoken.google.com/{project-id}";
               options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                   {
                       ValidateIssuer = true,
                       ValidIssuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/{project-id}",
                       ValidateAudience = true,
                       ValidAudience = "{project-id}",
                       ValidateLifetime = true
                   };
           });

However some answers have claimed this is not doing enough with no solution and some are years out dated.
I have also seen multiple methods in the Firebase.Admin SDK Nuget Package such as VerifyIdTokenAsync() that may be of use in doing this possibly with middleware?
If not what I have posted above, what is the proper way to authorize a Firebase JWT token in a .Net 6+ API? I want to continue to utilize attributes such as [Authorize] and [AllowAnonymous] in my implementation.

I haven't found any official document for introducing how to add firebase authorization into .net core web api in firebase site, so that I'm afraid we could only treat the firebase token as a general jwt token using jwt auth. Basic Jwt auth can help verify the token claims. I had a test before which verifying the role claim inside the token. I think you can also create custom policy to verify the tokens.
